# Is a solvable-by-finite group finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A group is solvable-by-finite if it has a normal solvable subgroup of finite index, does this mean this group is finitely generated? and why?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Do you know any soluble groups which are not finitely generated?

(**Hint 2:** Of course you do! But why is this an immediate counter-example?...)

---

Do you perhaps want the finite group $F$ to be the normal subgroup? This is a more interesting question. An group $G$ with $G/F\cong H$, $F$ finite, is finitely generated if and only if $H$ is finitely generated, and finitely presented if and only if $H$ is finitely presented. I am not using solubility here.

Answer (score 1):

I have one letter for you: $\mathbb{Q}$.